# Use jQuery to select an element that is contained within a comment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of a strange question, I'm wondering whether this is at all possible.

I'm parsing the DOM and there is an element like this:

```
<!-- <a class="pager" title="next" href="www.text.com">NEXT</a> -->
```

I need to be able to select this element with jQuery and return its `href` value. I've tried this:

`$('a.pager[title="Next"]').attr('href');`

but to no avail - from reading here [Selecting HTML Comments with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623734/selecting-html-comments-with-jquery) it seems that jQuery can only select elements with a particular `nodetype`.

Is it possible to return the value `www.text.com` from the `HTML` element above? To make things a little more tricky, i need to do it without relying on jQuery plugins - native Javascript or plain jQuery only please.

The following code returns the whole comment (as well as the text contained in all other comments on the page):

```
$("*")
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;})
    .each(function(){ alert(this.nodeValue);});
```

but I need to ONLY return the value of the `a href`, and no other comments. Ideas?

Comment: Can't you hide that element instead of commenting it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899216/selecting-text-between-comment-tags-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all you have to do is trim it :

```
var markup = $("*").contents().filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeType == 8;
}).get(0).nodeValue;

var href = $($.trim(markup)).attr('href');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/khkwy/1/)

**EDIT:**

to make it more specific you could always do some string matching :

```
var markup = $("*").contents().filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeType == 8 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('class="pager"') != -1;
});
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

You could also do :

```
var href = $.map($("*").contents(), function(el) {
    var html   = $.parseHTML( $.trim(el.nodeValue) ),
        anchor = $('<div />').append(html).find('a.pager[title="next"]');

    return el.nodeType === 8 && anchor.length ? anchor.attr('href') : null;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/khkwy/8/)

Comment: See edited question above - there are multiple comments on the page, I only need the one which contains `title='next'`, and find the href from that element.

Comment: @Jascination - does it matter, surely you know how to iterate, as you're doing it in the question ?

Comment: Kinda true, but I'm unsure about how to iterate and return only the comment that contains `title='next'`.

Comment: ah, prefect, `&& this.nodeValue.indexOf('class="pager"') != -1;` was exactly what I was looking for (still learning javascript so I'm often unsure of when to use these things!

Answer (score 2):

After selecting the comments, you need to parse their text content as HTML before you can reliably traverse the encoded DOM:

```
var matches = [];
$("*").contents().each(function(){
  if(this.nodeType != 8) return;
  var $div = $("<div>");
  $div.append(this.nodeValue);
  $div.find("a.pager[title='next']").each(function(){
    //replace $(this).attr("href") with this.href if you don't mind
    //relative URLs getting converted to absolute URLs
    matches.push($(this).attr("href"))
  });
});
```

Comment: This is close, but for some reason the code returns all comment URLs from the page. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zM5se/159/ click the button and note it shows a jsFiddle comment's url too.

Comment: @Jascination what do you mean? There is one comment with one `href` inside, and it is found. However, I did notice the browser converts the URL to an absolute URL. If that matters, `this.href` will need to be replaced: http://jsfiddle.net/zM5se/160/

Comment: @Jascination you have used a relative URL, which resolves to a link to JSFiddle. The `this.href` property reflects the actual target (at least in Chrome), even if the corresponding attribute doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("*")
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 8;})
    .each(function(){
        var regex = new RegExp('href=\"(.*)\"','g');
        var hrefValue = regex.exec(this.nodeValue)[1];
        alert(hrefValue);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you using `new RegExp` instead of the literal syntax? Also, this will crash if _any_ comment on the page doesn't have a HREF inside.

Comment: does not using literal syntax deserve a negative rating? lol. this will work on all comments in the page which have a href tag-attribute. And yes you are right, i need to check if the regex actually returns a match to avoid a crash. But it does point in the right direction :P. Rest is up to OP to improvise.

Comment: Crashing if there's a non-match is enough to warrant a downvote. I'm wondering if I should downvote Daniel's answer just for using a regex (I think I will). `new RegExp` is merely a red flag that deserves demanding an explanation. And no, the answers should not be incomplete when they claim they are complete.